# Sum of attributes in model with has_many :through association not working in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, has-many-through, model-associations

So I have 2 models. Meal & Food. A meal can hav multiple food items and a food item can be a part of many meals. Basically a many-to-many association. I did that with a has_many :through and the joining model is called MealsFood. When creating a new meal you choose via checkboxes what food items you want to add. The foods table has a column called "calories" and the meals table has a column called "total_calories" where it calculates the sum of all the food items in the meal.
The problem is that it isn't working.

Here's what I have so far...

**Models**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :foods, through: :meal_foods

    def calc_total_calories
        self.foods.sum(:calories)
    end
end

class MealFood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :food
end

class Food < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :meals, through: :meal_foods
end
```

**Meals Controller**

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @meal = Meal.new
    end

    def create
        @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
        @meal.calc_total_calories

        if @meal.save
            redirect_to @meal
        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    private

    def meal_params
        params.require(:meal).permit(:user_id, :meal_type, :date, 
  :total_calories, :total_carbohydrates, :total_fat, food_ids:[])
    end
end
```

**View (new action for meals)**

```
            <%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :meal_type %>
                    <%= f.select :meal_type, ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Morning Snack", "Afternoon Snack, Evening Snack"] %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <% Food.all.each do |food| %>
                        <%= check_box_tag "meal[food_ids][]", food.id %>
                        <%= food.name %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.submit class: "button button-highlight button-block" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

Notice the def calc_total_calories in the Meal model. It's what I use to calculate the calories, but it doesn't work. I use it in the create method in the Meals controller.
Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do your create params look like? And where do you use `foods_ids` to associate `foods` with a `meal`?

Comment: I have edited my post, you can now see the view.

Comment: I use food_ids in the checkbox form in the view.

Comment: The view doesn't answer either of my questions. You should be able to copy the params from your console (where your server is running). And somewhere (in your controller or model, e.g.) it would seem you need to take the `foods_ids` provided by the view and use them to associate the `foods` to the `meal` (unless just passing the array of ids does that - which would be news to me - but is not unimagineable).

Comment: I guess that it does automatically create the association, because when I create a new meal and I choose food items in the join table meal_foods association are created.

Comment: Interesting! Have you inspected the associations? Are they correct (correct `meal_id` and correct `food_id`)? If, in console, you instantiate a `@meal` from one of your created meals (e.g., `@meal = Meal.find_by(id: x)` and do `@meal.foods` do you get the correct (expected) foods? Do the foods have calories?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct in the database and in the console. I think that the problem is that I'm not passing in the arguments for which foods. Because in the console after I've initiated a meal when I do meal.foods.calories I get an error, but when I do meal.foods[1].calories I get the correct calories. Do you know how I can pass the id as an argument?

Comment: No. That is not the problem. `calories` is an instance method. `meal.foods` returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation`. So, you can't call `calories` on `foods`. What happens if you do `meal.foods.pluck(:calories)`? And, if you do `meal.foods.sum(:calories)` in console?

Comment: In the console I get an array with the calories of the food items when I do .pluck(:calories) and with .sum(:calories) I get the correct sum

Comment: And if you do `meal.calc_total_calories` what do you get?

Comment: I get the correct sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking, perhaps, that you want to do something like:

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
      @meal = Meal.new
  end

  def create
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)

    if @meal.save
      @meal.update(total_calories: @meal.calc_total_calories)
      redirect_to @meal
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

  def meal_params
    params.require(:meal).permit(:user_id, :meal_type, :date, :total_calories, :total_carbohydrates, :total_fat, food_ids:[])
  end

end
```

In your original code, you're not setting the `total_calories` attribute on `@meal`, just calling the `calc_total_calories` method (which is probably calculating total calories correctly).

In the answer provided by SRack, you're setting, but never saving the `total_calories` attribute.

`update` will both set and save the attribute.

BTW, you'll want to be sure to think about how you handle changing the `foods` associated with a `meal` or else your `total_calories` may become stale and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually doing anything with `calc_total_calories` - it's not assigned to anything in the controller, and not assigning *to* anything in the model.

You likely want the model method to assign it to something, as in the following:

```
def calc_total_calories
    self.total_calories = self.foods.sum(:calories)
end
```

That assumes a column on your `meal` model called `total_calories`.

Does that seem like what you're looking for? Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: I did try that, but it just assigns it to 0. It says in the database: total_calories: 0

Comment: Have you tested it out in the console? I.E. create a meal, create a couple of foods and assign them to this meal, then see if the method works? If this works ok (which I think it should), then it'd suggest the form isn't passing in the correct data - perhaps add this code to your question?

Comment: I tried it in the console and the code works, but it won't save it to the database. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you update your question with the params received in your controller please?

Comment: The code in my question is everything in my controller.

Comment: It's actually your server output I'm (and I believe @jvillian is) looking for - the actual params sent when you submit the form. If you check your server logs when you submit the form you'll find these. (Or you could use something like `10.times { puts "***" }; puts params` in the `create` action of your controller to help identify them.)

Answer (score 0):

You could update total calories after saving, in a callback.

```
after_save :update_calories

def update_calories
  update_attributes(total_calories: calc_total_calories)
  return true
end
```